# Clarification on SingleEmailMessage changes in Winter '16

Tags: email-template, singleemailmessage, winter16

Anyone knows the implications of this new method?

> **setTreatBodiesAsTemplate(treatAsTemplate)**
>
> Optional. If set to true, the subject, plain text, and HTML text bodies of the email are treated as template data.

Does it mean if treatAsTemplate = true I cannot use setToAddresses() because it cannot work with templates?

I could go in my DE and play with this (like I sometimes do) but I am looking for a proper answer.

Comment: Did you get any details on this? I'm confused as to exactly what this setting does.

Comment: Still no responses? I cannot figure out what is meant by treating the body as template data.

Comment: Unfortunately I dropped the ball and moved on :(